# How to add number of rows in section dynamically in tableview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults, objective-c-2.0

Note for the person who downvoted: This question was closed so many days back . If anyone find which is not  necessary please leave a comment

I have some textfield values & uiimage stored in one view controller. I have tableview in another view controller . I want store values using nsuserdefaults  in tableview and retrieve using nsuserdefaults then want to add rows dynamically as user enters?

Comment: Yes it is Possible , You can use reload table-view and add run-time number of row or number of sections in table-view

Comment: Can you please elaborate..?

Comment: What do you mean by "Add rows dynamically as user entered"? Do you want to add new cells at run time or do you wish to display the data in order entered by the user?

Comment: screen shot will help

Comment: Yes you can add cells on run time.

Comment: @PiyushMathur has already answered you.

Comment: @Uma make sure you are incrementing the array before reloading the table. If you are sure you are doing that, show your code to us.

Comment: This is never ending question. One will not be able to answer it properly unless the relevant code of both the viewController is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an `NSMutableArray` of this data like this:

```
NSMutableArray *cellLabelValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
```

In your tableView delegates do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return cellLabelValues.count;
}
```

You must have a button or something to receive user's intent to add new cells. Lets assume it calls this method:

```
   -(void) addNewCell:
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter New Value"
                                                message:@"  "   
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
    }
```

And write the delegate of `UIAlertView`. Make sure you have made your ViewController to be `UIAlertViewDelegate`:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSString *value = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
            [cellLabelValues addObject:value];
            [tableView reloadData];
    }
    }
```

What happens here is, user taps new cell button. It takes entry from user. Then it reloads the table after adding it to your array. When it reaches `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method, it sees that the array is now incremented by 1. So it will show one extra cell.

Comment: Then you will have to use `UITextField`. Use it to get text from user. When the entry ends, add it to the array and reload the tableview

Comment: I have just edited the code. Now it will take value from the user on runtime and show it  in table when you press okay

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a Mutable array with strings from textfield.

Then based on the array.count you can get the size of array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return array.count
}
```

and also don't forget to reload table view.

Comment: @Uma does your array count gets updated when you come to your `tableview`?

Comment: Do you add the new cell's data to the array before calling the [tableView relaodData] method?

Comment: @NSNoob i am unable to add to new cell .

Comment: @Uma Then, there is a problem with your array. You are not adding the objects into the array of textfield values correctly. If array count is not getting updated then how will data be shown correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two `UIViewControllers` `ViewController1` with `UITextFields` and `ViewController2` with `UITableView`

Now in ViewController2 declare an `NSMutableArray *dataArray`;

and add record in it from `ViewController1` before moving to `ViewController2`

In `ViewController2`
use this function

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return dataArray.count;
}
```

It will help.